# Python 2.7 - Two lists as dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

```
dict1 = open('dict1.txt','r')
dict2 = open('dict2.txt','r')

keys = []
values = []

for w in dict1:
   keys.append(w.strip())
   for key in keys:
       key


for x in dict2:
    values.append(x.strip())
    for val in values:
       val

dictionary = {key: val}
```

Text files contain 140 lines of single words. 'keys' is a list of words from the first file, 'values' is a list of words from the second file.

Whenever I print the dictionary, I get only the first pair. How to loop it inside dictionary so I get all 140 pairs?

I've tried doing this:

```
dictionary = {}
val = dictionary[key]
```

But I get 'KeyError' on the console. I know this is basic stuff but I've been struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily build the dictionary using `zip`:

```
for w in dict1:
   keys.append(w.strip())

for x in dict2:
    values.append(x.strip())

dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Your `KeyError` is due to the assignment being the wrong way around:

```
val = dictionary[key]
```

tries to assign what is currently in `dictionary` for the `key` (which is nothing) to `val`. Instead, it should be:

```
dictionary[key] = val
```

Your looping code is incorrect too:

```
for w in dict1:
   keys.append(w.strip())
   for key in keys: # looping over all keys so far each time
       key # doesn't do anything
```

And your first attempt:

```
dictionary = {key: val}
```

would create a new `dictionary` each time.

Comment: thank you the ZIP function was exactly what i was looking for. I thought `key` after the loop would simply declare that `key` is an item of list `keys`

Comment: No, `for key in keys:` assigns each item in `keys` in turn to the name `key`, but `key` on a line on its own does nothing at all.

Comment: So would this make sense if I didn't use ZIP function:
`for key in keys:`
    `for val in values:`
         `dictionary[key] = val`

Comment: No, that would loop over all values for each key, you would end up with all keys pointing to the last value. You could do: `for i in range(len(keys)): dictionary[keys[i]] = values[i]` or `for index, key in enumerate(keys): dictionary[key] = value[index]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip()` to combine the keys and values from the two files. You can produce the whole dictionary in one go with just two lines of code:

```
with open('dict1.txt','r') as keys, open('dict2.txt','r') as values:
    dictionary = {key.strip(): value.strip() for key, value in zip(keys, values)}
```

Your code loops over the two files and after each loop, `key` and `value` are bound still to the last value of each iteration.

Comment: In case the text files should be larger, it would be recommendable to use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`.

Comment: @Michael: That will not work if the keys file is the shorter file, as you can generate one repeating key only. You'd have to chain on a generator to the `keys` iterator to generate unique keys instead, and not use `izip_longest`.

Comment: Why? Afaik `izip` uses the same stop condition as `zip`. The behavior of `izip_longest` would be troublesome, but I don't think `izip`.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, no I misinterpreted your comment. I read it as *in case **one of** the text files should be larger*.

Comment: @Michael: I stayed away from `itertools.izip()` here because the OP stated the files are only 140 lines short and is an obvious beginner. Trying not to muddy the waters here, all that jazz.

Comment: Yeah basically i was looking for `zip` as I missed it somehow :) I will look into itertools sometimes in the future, for now I'm happy I can do this simple stuff. Lots of learning to do. But I like the two-line code, it's very elegant.